# Deploying Maqetta web workspace on MonoDroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, assets, xamarin, maqetta

I'm researching the possibility of using Xamarin (MonoDroid) and Maqetta for building a cross-platform app. Before I ask my question I must admint to being a novice Android developer.

I'm curious to how I'm supposed to deploy the workspace I get from Maqetta on my android device. The Zip-file I download contains a very simple web project with two views in a .html file similar to this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0LneuYl280&feature=plcp

The thing is that the .zip file contains over 6500 files, but OK... It's no more than 8 MB total. I drag the entire folder structure into the Assets folder on Visual Studio. When building I get the following error:

`Error  1 Invalid resource directory name: "assets". C:\Users\the\Desktop\Jobb\ImageCaptureApplication\ImageCaptureApplication\aapt.exe ImageCaptureApplication`

I don't get anything else from this error.

Whats the story about this Assets folder? If I dig deep into the web workspace I got from Maqetta and remove the 'dojox' folder under "/lib/dojo/" now at least I'm able to compile and build the code, but my web page doesn't look like anything.

Is the file number too high for the Assets folder? Could it be too many levels in the directory tree from Maqetta? I understand there is a limit of 1 MB per file, but a search tells me that it doesn't look like I'm violating this rule.

It would definatly be too cumbersome to manually scan through each release of the Maqetta web project trying to filter out unnecessary dependencies..

Answer (score 0):

Maqetta download size is a problem.  You can select/deselect individual libraries, but the Dojo library, when included, is included in its entirety.  You can edit the Dojo directory manually, as you have, or use the Dojo build script or the Dojo Web Builder (build.dojotoolkit.org) to create a smaller subset of the toolkit based on your usage.  Maqetta integration with the Dojo Web Builder is a work in progress.

Was this "assets" folder part of Dojo?  Did you identify where it was? The only problem I was aware of with the Android app builder is that it had a problem with underscores in filenames, but I believe that has been fixed.